# Trigger an event when a UIButton is dragged to a certain point of the screen? Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, drag-and-drop

How would I trigger an event when a draggable button is dragged to a certain point on the screen?

```
UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 300.0f, 300.0f, 42.0f)];
[btn1 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"View Fullscreen Decor"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[self.view addSubview:btn1];
[super viewDidLoad];
[myScrollView addSubview:btn1];

- (IBAction) imageMoved:(id) sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
UIControl *control = sender;
control.center = point;
}
```

Comment: Just compare your control.center point to whatever location you want on your super view, or child view. Then execute some function with `[self functionName];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (IBAction) imageMoved:(id) sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event{

  CGPoint touchPoint = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
  UIControl *control = sender;
  control.center = touchPoint;

  CGRect rectToCompare =  location you want on your super view;

   if (CGRectContainsPoint(rectToCompare, touchPoint)) {

         //trigger an event.         
   }
}
```

Comment: CGPoint touchPoint =  [(UIButton *)sender locationInView:self.view]; Does not work work for me. Am I doing something wrong.